# Websites for Ubuntu Virtual Environment

Tags: virtualization

I am new to Linux and need Ubuntu OS for some practice. Are there any websites where I can have my own virtual machine? I tried using Koding but they require some stack which I have no idea of. Please help with this.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Do you not want to dual-boot? Didn't you like VirtualBox? 

I mean why do you want a web-based solution?

Comment: For some reasons i can not use VirtualBox and dual-boot. If you can pls help with some web links, that'll be great!

Comment: Unfortunately, Google didn't help me. Someone with more knowledge surely will hep you here, sorry i can't.

Comment: You are probably looking for _virtual private server_ (VPS). https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+private+server+ubuntu+provider I hope you do not expect it to be free…